# How to determine the cause of a HashChangeEvent

Tags: javascript

How to determine if a HashChangeEvent was triggered by an user action in the page (click on a link, button, or something like), or manually input in the address bar?

Comment: It looks like there's no such event information supplied according to the specification for HashChangeEvent: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HashChangeEvent

Comment: Yes! I´ve checked MDN, but, actually I´m looking for some workaround.

Comment: There might be some way to shove [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee) in there and work with it.

Comment: @RahulDesai maybe if I use Function.caller, but nowadays according to Firefox: "TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions".

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to create some kind of wrapper that allows you to change the `window.location.hash` attribute, and call it from any elements that you want to be tracked. I have created an example on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eS4DzGIfUEFwhb5qiFis?p=preview) to demonstrate my idea of how that would be done. The example is pretty rudimentary, however. I think it conveys the point of what you're trying to do though.

I'll also put the example here, but it's not functional obviously. Let me know if you think this is going to cover your use case. I can tweak it if needed.

```
(function($) {

  'use strict';

  //Create a route function on the jQuery object
  //that we can use anywhere.

  /**
   * Wraps the setter for window.location.hash
   * and tracks who called it.
   * 
   * @param {Element} who The element that called route.
   * @param {string} hash The hash to set.
   */
  $.route = function(who, hash) {
    $.route.who = who;
    window.location.hash = hash;
  };

})(jQuery);
```

The code below shows how you can use the `$.route` function to track which element changed the `window.location.hash` value.

```
(function($) {

  'use strict';

  window.addEventListener('hashchange', function() {
    if ($.route.who) {
      //We know this was one of our tracked elements.
      alert(`Tag Name "${$.route.who.prop('tagName')}" triggered hash change.`);
    } else {
      //We'll assume that this wasn't being tracked, and therefore
      //is most likely to be caused by user input.
      alert('We could not track what triggered "hashchange".');
    }
    //Don't forget to reset this so that if an untracked input triggered this
    //it doesn't appear that it was tracked.
    $.route.who = null;
  });

  $(function() {

    $('.hash-change').click(function(e) {
      //Do some internal routing action that can track the caller.
      var $this = $(this);
      //Get the hash to set to the URL.
      var href = $this.attr('href') || $this.data('href');
      //Use our internal routing action to track the caller.
      $.route($this, href);

      //Prevent the default action of those hyperlinks by returning false.
      return false;
    });

  });

})(jQuery);
```

The HTML that I used in my example looks like this. Each one has the class hash-change. Elements that natively support href use it, others that don't use the dataset for the href.

```
<a class="hash-change" href="home">Home</a>
<a class="hash-change" href="about">About</a>
<input type="button" class="hash-change" data-href="contact" value="Contact" />
```

Those elements will be tracked and will use the `$.route` function to change the `hash` value. Anything that doesn't use the `$.route` function will not set the $.route.who value, and therefore, you can assume it was changed from some source, such as the user manually changing the hash.

Ultimately, whatever solution you implement will have to be a wrapper around existing functionality. Take a look at the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eS4DzGIfUEFwhb5qiFis?p=preview) example for a live demo.